# TensorFlow - GPU Acceleration only for training?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

Will utilizing GPU Acceleration with TensorFlow increase the speed of only the training of models or will it also help improve speed while using the model on data.

Most guides only talk about utilizing GPU acceleration for training purposes.


Also will it work with any of the [TensorFlow Models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) ? Even those run via shell scripts ?

In addition would it run on the shell scripts by default or does it require explicit coding to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work for both and yes it should make using the models faster even when not training (unless the model is really simple and the overhead of placing it on the GPU outweighs the performance cost.)  I do think using a GPU is less necessary for just evaluating the model.  When training often the data is batched together so that each train step contains multiple runs of the model.  Also the gradients need to be calculated which takes up a lot of compute time and memory.  The weights also need to be updated during training.  Therefore just making a simple forward pass is a lot faster.  I really think you would see a benefit if you needed to make a whole bunch of forward passes at once.

As for running tensorflow models through shell scripts, I would assume if they train on the GPU they will also run on the GPU.